# laravel homestead - different php version

Tags: laravel, homestead

We are using the latest homestead, where you can fill in the php version in homestead.yml.

I installed php 7.0 with "sudo apt-get install php7.0-fpm".
But from my point of view this php version is not used in my project.
I did a composer update and it takes php 7.1 as basis for the composer.lock.

How to use the php version 7.0 for my composer?

Comment: Not sure what're you asking. If in your composer.json is a dependency PHP 7.1, then you should install this version. Otherwise you can edit the composer.json file to use PHP 7.0.

Comment: The documentation has [a section about using other php versions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead#multiple-php-versions). You should give that a glance, as I believe that will address your issue.

Comment: Of cause I know the docu. What is not clear to me, if I go to "ssh my project" and I make composer update: from what file, it gets the info, which php version it should use? The doku says, we could use different php versions und we have only one composer.json.

Answer (score 0):

to check what is you cli php version run

```
php -v
```

to change it to php 7.0 run

```
php70
```